# Regex pattern for NNNNNN-N

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the pattern noted in the title (NNNNNN-N) where N is a digit from 0-9. I've seen plenty of partial examples but not quite what I need. I tried [0-9]{6}-[0-9] but can pass in 123456789-0 and it will pass as valid. What am I missing. BTW, haven't done Regexs in 20 years ...

Comment: `123456789-0` passes because it contains `456789-0` - you want your regex to match the entire string, or perhaps to match anything following white space. Please provide a code example and show in what language you expect to use the regex, since that may affect the answer. Also provide a representative example of the input, since it's not clear what exactly you want to match (and what not).

Comment: You need to anchor your regex to the string boundaries. Put `^` in front to match the beginning of the string and `$` at the end to match the end of the string: `^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]$`

Comment: I'm using C#. The input can be anything in the range 000000-0 to 999999-9; never any characters in any position; no white space within the string.

After testing,    ^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]$ works for me. Thank you.

Comment: Back to the drawing board. Valid range is **00000**-0 to 999999-9. Thought I could do `^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]|[0-9]{6}-[0-9]$` but it's letting 12345-56 or 12345678-9 through. Appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: Tried this: `^([0-9]{5}-[0-9])|([0-9]{6}-[0-9])$` but get the same results ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a boundary to your regex. `123456789-0` is matching because `456789-0` fits your regex pattern.

Here are some of your options:

1. word boundary `\b[0-9]{6}-[0-9]\b`.
2. whitespace boundary `\s[0-9]{6}-[0-9]\s`.
3. non-digit boundary  `[^0-9][0-9]{6}-[0-9][^0-9]`.
4. string boundary `^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]$`

[Try it out on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H1XX4V/1)

You will notice that they all match different combinations differently. You will also notice that for 2 and 3 it is also matching characters on either side... yikes! We can avoid this using parenthesis to form capture groups around the part we care about.

5. non-digit boundary w/ capture groups  `[^0-9]([0-9]{6}-[0-9])[^0-9]`.

[Try it out on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FQQ1zC/2)

One you have it in the capture group obtaining the information will depend on language and implementation. Without knowing the language it is hard to give more specific advise. The above assumed python for the regex but concept will be the same for any language, just implementation might be different.

Another thing to consider is using a the digit identifier rather than `[0-9]`. In python this will be `\d`. It matches more than just [0-9], but for most English use cases it makes no practical difference.